# SQL query executed several times instead of one

Tags: sql, symfony, repository

I have an identical SQL query is executed several times while I call it only once in my code.

This involves retrieving all of a user's notifications to display them on any page of my site, in the navbar. So I have a callable Service from Twig with a *notifications()* function :

```
public function notifications()
{
    $user   = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $result = $this->em->getRepository(Notification::class)->getLastNotifications($user, 20);

    return $result;
}
```

And in the Symfony profiler, I see that this request is called 3 times...

[Symfony Profiler Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTcbd.png)

At Twig level, I get the result of the function like this:

```
{% for notification in global_data.notifications %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can you tell me why Symfony executes this request 3 times?

Thanks

Comment: How this twig file is rendered? Is it the direct response of a controller or the file is included in some other file?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Why not run that request having XDebug enabled, or simply print the call stacktrace in that notifications method?

Comment: Did you try to set a variable with `global_data.notifications` before looping on it ?

`{% set notifications = global_data.notifications %}
{% for notification in notifications %}
{% endfor %}`